# Add exit after 'x' bars to supertrend strategy

Tags: tradingview-api

I am trying to modify the following supertrend script available in tradingview so that it will generate a sell when the supertrend generates a sell OR if the position has been open for 'x' bars.

thank you in advance!

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © KivancOzbilgic


//@version=4
strategy("SuperTrend STRATEGY", overlay=true)
Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title="Source")
Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
barcoloring = input(title="Bar Coloring On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
up=src-(Multiplier*atr)
up1 = nz(up[1],up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
FromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 1, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2018, title = "From Year", minval = 999)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 1, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 999)
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)       
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false
longCondition = buySignal
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, when = window())
shortCondition = sellSignal
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, when = window())
buy1= barssince(buySignal)
sell1 = barssince(sellSignal)
color1 = buy1[1] < sell1[1] ? color.green : buy1[1] > sell1[1] ? color.red : na
barcolor(barcoloring ? color1 : na)
```

I tried various ways of adding the exit after 'x' bars but I am very new to pine script and could not get the script to work properly